# Redshift - Generate Series with a maximum value dependent on the result of another query

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

In redshift, I'm trying to generate a series based on the maximum length of the SUPER array. Here's my code so far:

```
with actions_count as (
    select id, coalesce(get_array_length(actions), 0) as number_of_actions
    from user
)

select * from generate_series(0, (select max(number_of_actions) from actions_count), 1)
```

It works just find if I replace `(select max(number_of_actions) from actions_count)` with `10`. How can I use the result from a query along with redshift's `generate_series` function?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that with generate_series you can't.  Generate_series() is a leader node only function that cannot be combined with compute node data.

You need to create a recursive CTE to make the sequence you desire.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html

There are a number of existing answers in SO for creating a series (ints, dates, etc) with a Redshift recursive CTE.  So I won't recreate that here but reach out if help is needed with it.